# SQL - using result from subquery

Tags: android, sql, json, sqlite

I have two tables in my SQLLite database. I am trying to get back the drinks that can be made with the ingredients typed in.

I am trying to formulate this query to get what I want.

## **Table Drinks**

Columns

> drink_id | title | ingredients | directions | ingredientsNum

Sample row looks like

> 1 | Papa Smurf | 1 crushed blue popsicle, 8 oz Kool-Aid , 4 oz vodka | The directions | 3

## **Table Ingredients**

Columns

> drink_id | ingredient

Sample row looks like

> 1 | blue popsicle

## My Query at the moment

This is my partial pseudocode at what I want to return (after I get this I'll dynamically put in terms to query).

I want to return all drinks that have the amount of inputs to be equal to or more than the drinks ingredient number, and those inputted ingredients match all the ingredients needed in the drink.

```
SELECT drinks.title, drinks.ingredients, drinks.directions
FROM drinks, (SELECT count(ingredients._id) as ingredientNumber FROM ingredients
WHERE ingredients.ingredient LIKE '%rum%'
GROUP BY ingredients._id) as foundIngredients
WHERE drinks.ingredientsNum = foundIngredients.ingredientNumber;
```

### Can anybody help me towards getting the best suited query or even giving me some hints on restructuring my database model? I just made this database from a long JSON file of 80k lines.

Comment: Is this your actual schema? You've denormalized the ingredients data by including it in two places? What is the relationship between the tables? It seems like you need a join table containing the foreign keys drink_id and ingredient_id. Could you clarify?

Comment: Yes this is the actual schema. I mean I can change it around however best suits the best query. I am trying to query this on an android phone and want it pretty fast. I thought it might be faster to put all the ingredients already split up by the actual delimeter in my program (|) into the ingredients table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query reflecting clarified question:

```
SELECT drinks.title, drinks.ingredients, drinks.directions
FROM drinks
WHERE drinks.ingredientsNum = (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM ingredients
    WHERE (
        ingredients.ingredient LIKE '%rum%'
        OR ingredients.ingredient LIKE '%coke%'
        OR ingredients.ingredient LIKE '%vodka%'
        -- the same goes for each ingredient
    )
    AND ingredients.drink_id = drinks.drink_id
)
```

Similarly, if you allow a drink to have extra ingredients *besides all specified*:

```
SELECT drinks.title, drinks.ingredients, drinks.directions
FROM drinks
WHERE drinks.ingredientsNum >= [number of input ingredients]
AND [number of input ingredients] <= (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM ingredients
    WHERE (
        ingredients.ingredient LIKE '%rum%'
        OR ingredients.ingredient LIKE '%coke%'
        OR ingredients.ingredient LIKE '%vodka%'
        -- the same goes for each ingredient
    )
    AND ingredients.drink_id = drinks.drink_id
)
```

Comment: I want to return all drinks that satisfy the given inputs. For example: `Drink needs rum and vodka to make and the input is rum and vodka.` `Drink has rum, coke, and vodka to make and the input is rum, coke, and vodka.`

Comment: I edited what I want a little bit. If 3 ingredients are inputted I want to return drinks with 3 ingredients and those ingredients all match the inputted ingredients.

Comment: No the person cannot go to the store and buy what they don't have. So the ingredients inputted has to be equal or more than the drinks ingredient number and the ingredients have to match.

Comment: Ok I think you hit it on the dot there. I was really close. I will try this in a little bit and tell you how it goes. If you could vote my question up I can vote yours up (I need 15 rep).

Comment: Take your time. I edited it a little bit to work in case of several ingredients matching one single input - like when a drink has *coke* and *coke light* and the input is *coke*. This will work for small to medium DBs but for larger you should consider normalization like described by Mike Brant.

Comment: Why would I want to normalize this database when all I'm trying to do is SELECT's?

Comment: Well, DB normalization isn't jest about good-looking schema. When properly done it allows generating better query plans used by DBMS to figure out how to actually perform any query, SELECTs included. Also it allows application to have less (ideally none) data redundancy which translates to less data to process and in turn to faster execution. But from my experience it can be an overkill when it comes to mobile devices.

Comment: Well with this database design I'm not doing anything with ingredients from the drinks table. It's just used to displaying the actual drink so I don't have to make another query to figure out the the ingredients in a drink.

Comment: Yeah every time I run this query it freezes my SQLLite database browser. Sounds like I have too large of tables.

Comment: Just from curiosity: what is row count for each table? Do you have any indexes on any columns?

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is a little weird in that typically you might actually use 3 tables to truly normalize this data structure (drinks, ingredients, drink_ingredients or similar). However, since you are doing a text search and you already have all the ingredient names in the drinks table, you can simply query on the drinks table:

```
SELECT title, ingredients, directions
FROM drinks
WHERE ingredients LIKE '%rum%'
AND ingredients LIKE '%vodka%'
... // add more ingredients as needed
```

Make sure you have an index on the ingredients field.  Note you can change the `AND` to `OR` if you want to return all drinks with rum and/or vodka.

Comment: Now how would I make the SQL statement make sure all the ingredients in a drink are satisfied?

Comment: Well then you would likely need to think about normalizing your data, because a text search is not going to get you what you want.  You would probably need to do a text search on the ingredients to determine ingredient id's, and then utilize and drinks_to_ingredients many-to-many join table to make your search.  You also will probably need to break you task up into multiple queries in order to use efficient queries.

Comment: Why would I want to normalized this database when all I want to do is SELECT's? I'm not doing any changing of any sort.